# New Office365 Library does not have SP object, is JSOM dead?

Tags: office-365

Related Yammer conversations:

- https://www.yammer.com/itpronetwork/#/threads/inGroup?type=in_group&feedId=3903794
- https://www.yammer.com/itpronetwork/#/threads/inGroup?type=in_group&feedId=4597220

---

The tools on top of MDS that relied on some Delta DIV elements are broken too because there is no MDS related stuff to be found in the page source.

Was MDS EODed as well?

And where most people switch to Angular (including many MVPs)

Some people at Microsoft seem to hold on to KnockOut (at its peak 3 years ago)

[image]

[image]

Trend analysis of "Angular" not included because it would flatline this blue KnockoutJS trend...

Comment: Think of the new library as more of a OD4B type page than a SharePoint page. So the typical stuff you might expect to find in SharePoint will not be present there.

Comment: No SP, no JSOM, no MDS, No SOD, No CSR ... It sure makes life simple again :-)   But I do love how they do "View In File Explorer" ... (they open a new Tab in the "Old" sharePoint View and there kick of the Explorer)

Comment: could you please take screenshots of those two yammer links?

Comment: No, they are hundreds of messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be part of the "New SharePoint Document Library Experiences"? Leaving as an answer as it is too long for a comment.

> New SharePoint Document Library Experiences
>  MC44849
>
> We are changing the experience for SharePoint Online document
>   libraries. You’ll begin seeing this new feature starting April 6.
>   How does this affect me?
>
> In the new document library, documents can be displayed using classic
>   or thumbnail views for a graphic look and feel. Libraries now support
>   uploading folders and links in addition to single files. Documents can
>   be grouped with views directly from the library home screen, and
>   selected documents can be pinned to a highlighted section at the top
>   of the library. A new document information panel displays in concert
>   with the document library, and allows easy access to previews,
>   activity history, sharing, and metadata editing. Document management
>   functions are moved to a clean, responsive menu pane and the Ribbon is
>   removed from the UI.   What do I need to do to prepare for this
>   change?
>
> Inform your help desk staff of this change. Please click Additional
>   information to learn more
>
> Additional Information:
>   https://support.office.com/article/3b5976dd-65cf-4c9e-bf5a-713c10ca2872

Comment: Yes it is. And besides removing the Ribbon... they removed a whole lot more... Well.. strictly speaking they did  **not _remove_** anything.. as it is a whole new UI and (it seems like) underlying technology...